# Finding a value - problem in the question?

Tags: calculus

Given $ f(x)=a(\operatorname{tg}(x)\sqrt{\cos{2x}+1}) ,\;\;\; 0.5\le x\le 3.2 $.
and the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at the inflection point is $-\sqrt{2}$.
They asking me to show that $a=1$.
But after calculating I got a term with absolute function.

Comment: Using $\sqrt{\cos 2x + 1} \; = \; \sqrt{\left(2{\cos}^2 x - 1 \right) + 1} \; = \; \sqrt{2}| \cos x |,$ the given function simplifies significantly (to a certain piecewise defined function).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - true and that's what i got but if you don't simplify you get another value for a.

Comment: I get a mess trying to take the 2nd derivative without making any obvious trigonometric simplifications, so it's almost certainly the case that the intended solution follows the path I suggested earlier. Also, given the mess that one gets, it wouldn't surprise me that an error slipped into your calculations. I just posted a fairly detailed solution, but I got $a = -1$ instead of $a = 1.$

Comment: Is your $\operatorname{tg} x$ really $\tan x$?

Comment: @vonbrand- yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the function isn't defined for $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. So I'll consider the domain to be $0.5 \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ along with $\frac{\pi}{2} < x \leq 3.2,$ that is, the set $[0.5, \; \frac{\pi}{2}) \cup (\frac{\pi}{2}, \; 3.2].$ We also need to assume $a \neq 0.$

Using

$$\sqrt{\cos2x + 1} \;=\; \sqrt{\left(2{\cos}^2 x - 1 \right) + 1} \;=\; \sqrt{2}|\cos x|,$$

it follows that $f(x) = a \sqrt{2} \sin x$ when $0.5 \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f(x) = -a \sqrt{2} \sin x$ when $\frac{\pi}{2} < x \leq 3.2.$

Therefore, $f'(x) = a \sqrt{2} \cos x$ when $0.5 \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f'(x) = -a \sqrt{2} \cos x$ when $\frac{\pi}{2} < x \leq 3.2.$

Also, $f''(x) = -a \sqrt{2} \sin x$ when $0.5 \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f''(x) = a \sqrt{2} \sin x$ when $\frac{\pi}{2} < x \leq 3.2.$

Solving $f''(x) = 0$ gives no solution for $0.5 \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and gives $x = \pi$ for $\frac{\pi}{2} < x \leq 3.2.$

Thus, the only candidate for an inflection point is $x = \pi.$ Moreover, $x = \pi$ **actually is an inflection point**, since $f''(x)$ has the same sign as $a$ for all values of $x$ a little smaller than $\pi$ and $f''(x)$ has the opposite sign as $a$ for all values of $x$ a little larger than $\pi.$

We're told that $f'(\pi) = -\sqrt{2},$ so we get $-a\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi) = -\sqrt{2},$ which implies $a = -1.$ **Note that I don't get your answer.**